# Excel cell text turned yellow with double horizontal lines top and bottom

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

All I did was move the three cells down 1 row. Why did this happen, and how do I make it normal color again?

I think the padding also increased.

Comment: I think this is an indication that you created a loop in cell reference. Cell A1 refers to Cell A2 and Cell A2 refers to Cell A1 which creates an infinite loop and Excel stops calculating these cells.

Comment: They don't refer to any cells. They contain very simple formulas like `=60-10` or `=50-.5`.

Comment: Could this be just formatting? Click the bottom cell that has the 50 in it then click the Format Painter button on the Home tab and then click and drop over the top 50 and 49.5 to sent the formatting the same as the bottom 50.

Comment: If it's formatting then I definitely didn't format it like that. All I did was drag the cells down 1 position. Why would that cause a format change? I was able to get rid of it by clicking `Normal` in Styles, but the cause of this is still a mystery to me. It's also consistent. If I do it again then it happens again.